# Simplify if condition boolean expression

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I have this `if-condition` in my code:

```
if (a||a&&!b){
// do some stuff
}
```

with that intial values from my `junit test`:

```
boolean a=true, b = true;
```

as I recognized later the statement can be simplified to:

```
if (a&&b)
```

becomes green: `Assert.assertTrue(a||a&&!b == a&&b);`

Are there any further simplifications? How could I have recognized that this boolean expression could be simplified?

Comment: `a || a && !b` is not equal to `a && b`. It is equal to just `a`.

Comment: I'd *strongly* recommend using whitespace to make your code easier to read... and parentheses where it might take a while to work out precedence would help too.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha actually does boolean algebra simplification. It might take a little converting the answer it gives you to make it compatible with your programming language, but the concept works and checks out fine. [Here's a link to the page](http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/BooleanAlgebra.html)

Comment: Boolean algebra allows you to simplify boolean expressions.

Comment: Yes. Boolean algebra is there for simplifying.

Comment: You could use [Karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) for simplify boolean logic. With 3 or more variables is the best way

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: That test becomes green Assert.assertTrue(a||a&&!b == a&&b);

Comment: I know that boolean algebra does that. I wrote an android app to simplify boolean expressions step by step :)
Unfortunality my app has that one bug that I doent recognize the above case...

Comment: @StefanBeike Just because you used a specific combination of values for `a` and `b` where the results match does not mean that the expressions are equivalent. They aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a || a && !b
```

is not equal to

```
a && b
```

It is equal to just `a`.

I suppose that in your JUnit test you used a specific combination of values for `a` and `b` where the results match, but that does not mean that the expressions are equivalent—and in fact they aren't. A quick way to convince yourself of that is checking the combination

```
a = true, b = false;
```

Your original expression clearly yields `true` for all cases where `a == true`, but your second expression will yield `false` whenever `b == false`.

As for a formal proof of equivalence to just `a`, take the expansion

```
a == a && (b || !b)
  == a && b || a && !b
```

Plugging into your original expression:

```
a || a && !b == a && b || a && !b || a && !b
             == a && b || a && !b
             == a
```

Answer (score 7):

Just check the *truth table* (I've added parentheses)

```
  a || (a && (!b))

  a|b|result
  ----------
  T|T|T 
  T|F|T 
  F|T|F 
  F|F|F
```

As we can see, the formula *doesn't depend* on `b`, and can be simplified to only

```
  a
```

Finally

```
  if (a) {
    // do some stuff
  }
```

For formulae with *many variables* when truth table is too long for manual analysis you can use *Karnaugh maps* as Eomm proposed.

Comment: If you are right my app works right. It simplifies with one step(absorbation)

Answer (score 4):

One common technique used to simplify complex Boolean expressions is [*Karnaugh Maps*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map). It is relatively easy to learn, and it can help you produce shorter expressions, or even build Boolean expressions from a truth table.

Karnaugh Map for your expression is very simple - it looks like this:

[image]

It simplifies to `a`, not `a && b`.